# Xpath for Next Page - Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am scraping Walmart website using `Scrapy`, and I am trying it out for one category but I have trouble nailing down an xpath for next page. Here is what I have, can someone help?

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="paginator outline"]/ul/li/a/@href')
```

Walmart URL to inspect: 
https://www.walmart.com/browse/electronics/tvs/3944_1060825_447913

Comment: When you mean for the next page, do you mean the carousel paginator?

Answer (score 0):

The process is to find the `<li>` tag after the active page link.  The active page link is found using `//*[@class="active"]`, and so you would have to find the index of this particular active `<li>` in respect to that of all the actual `<li>` tags.  To find all the `<li>` tags, use this xpath `//*[@class="paginator-list"]/li`. As you could see in the aria-label class, it would say 'Page x of y selected'.  The `x` would be the index, and so you would have to just search for the `x+1` page.

To find the values in the `<li>` or the aria-label class, you need to use the `.text()` and `.extract()` function.

This will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I tried to extract all the li page tags using paginator list://*[@class="paginator-list"]/li. I do not get any results. This container with the paginators "midas-sponsored-container-middle-1", does not show up when I try to extract all the div id tags too. Not sure what I am missing.